# Cakephp 2.0 Auth doesn't redirect to users/login

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.0

I have some code in AppControler::beforeFilter()

```
$this->Auth->authorize      = array('Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'));
$this->Auth->loginAction    = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

But the Auth does not redirect me to the users/login when I'm trying to load nonpublic action in browser. Instead it redirects me to the '/'. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you have not granted permissions to the Login action in the users controller. Add this to the top of the users controller:

```
function beforeFilter(){
   parent::beforeFilter();
   $this->Auth->allow('login');
}
```

As a side note, the loginAction already defaults to /users/login. The same goes for the logoutRedirect. Try removing both as they are not really needed since you are already wanting it to go to the default location.

**UPDATE**

Have you included the component in the top of the AppController?

```
public $components = array('Auth');
```

The other thing to confirm is that you are not already logged in. If you are already logged in but have not granted permission to a specific action within a controller for logged in users, it can redirect as well.

Comment: I already have beforeFilter with $this->Auth->allow('login') in UsersController. And when I go to the 'users/login' I see the login page.